# Photoshop Scripting: batch replace colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I'm trying to write a script that will replace the colors of all same-colored shapes, including those on non-visible layers. I am new to Photoshop scripting, but I imagine the pseudocode would work something like this:

```
for (all shape layers)
  if (fill color = #123456)
    fill color = #000000
```

Is this possible to do?

I tried running the script [here](https://gist.github.com/theinsanecow/895810), but got an error at 'executeActionGet' (This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop). I am using Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Except offcourse `if (fill color = #123456)` is not entirely ambigious to photoshop.

Comment: What was the error? According to [Adobe’s own documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf#page47), `executeActionGet` is available in CS6, too, so it's more likely it's the parameter (the `actionReference`) something’s wrong with.

Answer (score -1):

I have used ChangeColor in the past to achieve this. Here is the GitHub repo > https://gist.github.com/theinsanecow/895810

It sounds like this is exactly what you're after, but even if it's just good as a reference point for your script, it should help.

Comment: OP said: "I tried running the script **[here](https://gist.github.com/theinsanecow/895810)**, but got an error at 'executeActionGet' ..."